# Mocking a Qt slot with unittest

Tags: python, pyqt5, python-unittest

I'm switching from PySide2 to PyQt5 and am getting a TypeError in one of my tests.

The test checks for whether `exit_action` actually calls the `close` method.

**bug.py**

```py
# bug.py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui
# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.exit_action = QtWidgets.QAction('&Exit', self)
        self.exit_action.triggered.connect(self.close)

        self.file_menu = self.menuBar().addMenu('&File')
        self.file_menu.addAction(self.exit_action)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()
    app.exec_()
```

**test_bug.py**

```py
# test_bug.py
# python3 -m unittest test_bug.TestMainWindowExitAction
import bug
import unittest
import unittest.mock

from PySide2 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtTest
# from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui, QtTest


if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])


class TestMainWindowExitAction(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.main_window = bug.MainWindow()

    def test_exit_action_trigger_closes_application_with_mock(self):
        close_mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock()
        self.main_window.closeEvent = close_mock
        self.main_window.exit_action.triggered.emit()
        close_mock.assert_called_once()

    # def test_exit_action_trigger_closes_application_without_mock(self):

    #     self.called=0
    #     def my_close(arg):
    #         print(f"HERE {arg}")
    #         self.called+=1

    #     self.main_window.closeEvent = my_close
    #     self.main_window.exit_action.triggered.emit()

    #     self.assertEqual(self.called, 1)
```

It works great with Pyside2.  With PyQt5, it gives an error:

```bash
TypeError: invalid argument to sipBadCatcherResult()
Aborted
```

The error happens when `exit_action.triggered` is emitted.

If I instead run `test_exit_action_trigger_closes_application_without_mock`, everything runs fine:

```py
HERE <PyQt5.QtGui.QCloseEvent object at 0x7f73488e75e0>
.
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.005s

OK
```

It's not clear to me what the "right" way to test this is.  Even though the nested def works, it's not obvious how it works (although I do understand it).  If I mock `close` instead of `closeEvent`, the mock isn't called during testing, despite the action closing the application when I manually run it.  It's not clear to me if the problem is with PyQt5 (i.e. sip) or with `unittest.mock` or if everything is fine and I've just confused myself.

Comment: PySide and PyQt have slightly different behaviors when dealing with object destruction and garbage collection, and the timing that results into an application quit might differ assuming the default (quitOnLastWindowClosed)[https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qguiapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop] property is set, so it's depending on "when/what" actually closes the application. Sorry, I'm not an expert in unit testing, but based on my assumption, the real question I'd ask is: what are you actually trying to test, and for what reason?

Comment: The test is to confirm the behavior of the exit action (in the menu) when triggered.  The expected behavior is for the application to exit.  It does this by checking if the `close` method is called.  That's not a foolproof approach, yet probably good enough to catch editing mistakes.

Comment: Then it's probably not a good test indeed: while `self.close()` *does* call `closeEvent()`, that doesn't automatically cause the application to quit, and that is especially important if you *do* override `closeEvent()` (for instance, to show a dialog and/or prevent closing under certain conditions). If you actually want to check for the application to quit then consider waiting for the [`aboutToQuit`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#aboutToQuit) signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add a return value to the mock then it should work (works on my machine at least)

```
close_mock = unittest.mock.MagicMock(return_value=None)
```

If you don't specify a return value then it will return another mock object which, I guess, upsets some type check within PyQt5/sip.